# Convert 16 bpp image to 8 bpp greyscale in c++

Tags: c++, labwindows

I have image source that generates images in 16 bpp. I have this info in unsigned char * buffer. I need to display image, which I cant using Labwindows directly in 16-bit. It doesnt support 16 bit. 
How to convert 16bpp in 8 bpp to show it Labwindows using NEWBITMAP();

I am a new to this conversion. Please help me write conversion in c++

Comment: Iterate over your character buffer and copy the most significant byte of each pixel into a new buffer that's half the size.

Comment: @JohnFilleau that's the naive way to do it.  It would be better to make a pass over the image to get the min/max then scale it.  It would be even better to use dithering to get more levels out of those 8 bits.

Comment: @Mark better is subjective, but good suggestions.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: looks better. Can you give an example in c++. I am new to this field, sorry

Comment: Sorry, I'm not at all familiar with Labwindows. Otherwise I would have left an answer.